# Can I develop Atom editor package with ES6? (not CoffeeScript)

Tags: ecmascript-6, atom-editor

Can I develop atom package with ES6?
I don't want to write CoffeeScript.

Atom reportedly using Chrome and V8, so I think it can use to develop package.

Comment: https://discuss.atom.io/t/es6-package-generator-and-guides/18127

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Atom can compile CoffeeScript, TypeScript, or ES6 (via Babel). To use Babel, just put

```
'use babel'
```

at the top of your file. If you only use the subset of ES6 that the version of Chrome that Atom uses implements, you don't even need Babel.